# SQL Find a result 1 field below the search

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, window-functions, sql-limit

As part of a project to learn SQL I've downloaded the dictionary as a .csv and set up a table (1 column with 307,104 words in it called 'Words').

I'm stuck on a some queries, which are:

- What word comes after 'Database'
- What word comes 2 words after 'Database'
- What word come before 'Database'
- What word comes 2 words before 'Database'

I can't find the keyword relating to this type of query, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the words with `row_number()` in a common table expression (if your database supports these features), then filter in the outer query:

```
with cte as (
    select word, row_number() over(order by word) rn
    from mytable 
)
select c.word
from cte c
where c.rn = (
    select c1.rn from cte c1 where c1.word = 'database'
) + 1
```

This gives you the word that immediately follows  "database". You can change the final `+ 1` to get the other results (for example, to get the word two positions before, you would use `- 2`).

Another option uses a row-limiting query.

To get the next word:

```
select word
from mytable
where word > 'database'
order by word
limit 1
```

The word two positions after:

```
select word
from mytable
where word > 'database'
order by word
limit 1, 1
```

Preceding word:

```
select word
from mytable
where word < 'database'
order by word desc
limit 1
```

The word two positions before:

```
select word
from mytable
where word < 'database'
order by word desc
limit 1, 1
```

Note: the syntax of the row-limiting clause varies across databases.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this, works perfectly, not used the WITH common table expression before

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions like `LAG()` (for words before 'Database') and `LEAD()` (for words after 'Database'):

```
select t.result 
from (
  select columnname, lag(columnname, 1) over (order by (select null)) result
  from words
) t
where t.columnname = 'Database'
```

Change `columnname` to the name of your column.
This query returns the word before 'Database' and if you change 1 to 2 you will get the word 2 rows before 'Database'.
Depending on your database you may omit `order by (select null)` from the `over` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the word after database:

```
select word
from dictionary
where word > database
order by word
fetch first 1 row only;
```

For two words after:

```
select word
from dictionary
where word > database
order by word
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```

The queries for the "before" are similar but the sort and comparison are in opposite directions.

You can start to get fancy using window functions.  For instance, if you wanted all the words from 2 before to 2 after, you can use a windows count:

```
select word
from (select d.*,
             sum(case when word = 'database' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by word range between 2 preceding and 2 following) as cnt_database
     from dictionary d
    ) d
where cnt_database > 0;
```

However, with an index on `(word)`, the first approach is going to be faster.